# Ubuntu Server Port Forwarding Issue

Tags: ubuntu, port, forwarding

I've created a web server from a spare computer and Ubuntu Server but I'm having trouble making it viewable from the outside. I've set up port forwarding on my Netgear router but it still dosen't work. Any ideas?
Also, the link is: server.fishbe.in

Answer (score 1):

You need the `Listen` directive in your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, e.g.

`Listen 81`

You will want to change the `NameVirtualHost` directive to reflect your new port choice as well.

Restart Apache and it will then be listening on port 81. Re-setup your port forwarding and try again. If it is still a no-go, try a different, random port, as 81 might be filtered as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it is at your house some ISPs block port 80. Port 81 is usually unblocked and is well known for HTTP.

Make sure a webserver such as Apache is running

```
$ netstat -plant
```

or

```
$ ps aux | grep apache
```

make sure DNS is properly configured.

Comment: Do I have to change anything server side to get it to go to port 81?

Comment: @phil Apache has to start on port 81, or you write a netcat script that routes 80 to 81